# Compare code from the files of two directores

Tags: php, ftp, compare, comparison

I have several files & folders in 
domain.com
and a working copy in:
domain.com/beta

I want to compare the code of all files (php files) in the beta folder with the ones in the main folder and just view the files in which the codes do not match.

I've googled this topic, but was only able to find solution to compare single files at a time.

Comment: You can use `winmerge` on windows, or `meld` on linux.

Comment: On linux might be `diff` too.  Most revision control systems like git and svn also provide methods.

Comment: I used winmerge and it worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use total commander for this... the menu command "commands - synchronize directories" ... shows you which files are different, then you have to merge one by one http://www.ghisler.com/screenshots/en/08.html, to merge a pair, just double click it, If you are on linux, then I really can not help

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check if the file content is something else, you can build a checksum. Just make a new PHP script, iterate through the folders (opendir/readdir) and build for example a md5 checksum. This should be compared with the same file from the other directory. A checksum is better than a complete comparison of a file, because it needs less ressources.

In general, you should use a versioning tool like git. Then you do not have such problems.

Comment: For addition, you can create checksums from shell. If you have bash access, just use _md5sum ./*_ or something like this.